# amount for working hours of volunteer on an event

Tags: civievent, contacts, civivolunteer

I need to know how many hours a volunteer works for us. Is this possible to set up using events?

Here's how I have configured CiviCRM:

- a volunteer is a contact and has a relationship with our company
- this volunteer is an event participant with the role Project Staff.

I don't have the CiviVolunteer extension.

Answer (score 2):

Without CiviVolunteer, you can add a numeric custom field for participants and call it volunteer hours.  When you register the participant for the event, or by editing it later, you can record those hours in the field.

You will still need to have a way to total up the hours if you want to say something like, "Dave volunteered 20 hours at events this year."  You'll need to build a custom report or at the very least export participants and sum the values in a spreadsheet.

CiviVolunteer was really envisioned with your sort of situation in mind, so you might consider downloading it.

Comment: thx. do i have do download the 4.7 to use civivolunteer?
and is there a risk for the system to download the 4.7?

Comment: No, you should be able to run CiviVolunteer for 4.4 or 4.6.  Go into your Manage Extensions page, and it should be under the Add New tab.

Comment: i have civi 4.5.2. but i can t find the civivolunteer where you discribed. could this be a problem of our hoster? thx.